# Simulating Raw Input on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, input, raw-input

I have an application that does some complicated things with raw input and I would like to have some automated tests for it. This is the code that sends input albeit chopped down a bit to make it easier to follow.

Sending:

```
GetRawInputDeviceList(nullptr, &numDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
rawInputDeviceList = new RAWINPUTDEVICELIST[numDevices];
GetRawInputDeviceList(rawInputDeviceList, &numDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

HGLOBAL hRaw = ::GlobalAlloc(GHND, sizeof(RAWINPUT));
RAWINPUT *pRaw = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(::GlobalLock(hRaw));
pRaw->data.keyboard.MakeCode = 30;
pRaw->data.keyboard.Flags = 0;
pRaw->data.keyboard.Reserved = 0;
pRaw->data.keyboard.VKey = 0x43;
pRaw->data.keyboard.Message = WM_KEYDOWN;
pRaw->data.keyboard.ExtraInformation = 0;
pRaw->header.dwType = RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD;
pRaw->header.dwSize = sizeof(RAWINPUT);
pRaw->header.hDevice = rawInputDeviceList[0].hDevice;
pRaw->header.wParam = (WPARAM)RIM_INPUT;
::GlobalUnlock(hRaw);

SendMessage(hWnd_, WM_INPUT, (WPARAM)RIM_INPUT, (LPARAM)hRaw);
```

Receiving:

```
case WM_INPUT:
  UINT size = 0;  
  if(GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)))
    return GetLastError();
```

The return value from GetLastError() is ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE(6). However I can read the handle fine if I use GlobalLock it myself.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645596(v=vs.85).aspx
  "lParam: A handle to the RAWINPUT structure. This comes from the lParam in WM_INPUT."

I've tried just using a pointer and I get the same error message. I've tried with/without unlocking, as well as using LocalAlloc/LocalLock instead. I've tried with PostMessage and it's all the same result, and I am now out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried calling GetRawInputData directly instead of using SendMessage?

Comment: Are you doing this from an external process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `WM_INPUT` message cannot be sent between processes. Like `WM_PAINT`, it is a synthesized message which can only be properly generated by the system itself. The `lParam` is not just an `HGLOBAL` containing the data, it is an opaque handle understood only by the raw input code.

Raw Input messages are generated directly by the `GetMessage`/`PeekMessage` internals, and the associated objects are cleaned up by `DefWindowProc`. `SendMessage` will not marshal the `LPARAM` for `WM_INPUT`, because the code to do so wasn't written as it is not intended to be used in that way.

Comment: My test application is the same process as what is being tested. I understand your other point which is what is stopping me doing what I want. I think I can still test my application if I create a virtual device which can create messages from a drivers point of view.