# Moving the cursor to specified position in another application

Tags: c#, winapi, events, cursor, mouse

I have a game that uses FPC and my app. The games locks the cursor on the center of the screen and just moves the camera in the game when mouse moved. I have to move the cursor to specified point on the screen (in the game). I've tried`SetCursorPos`, `SendInput`, `mouseevent` and `Cursor.Position` but no one of these did the stuff. Only this code (I found it somewhere, but I can't find it again ;)) moved the mouse, but to incorrect positon (other functions did nothing if the game was on the top):

```
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;

public static void MoveTo(float x, float y)
{
    float min = 0;
    float max = UInt16.MaxValue;

    int mappedX = (int)Remap(x, 0.0f, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, min, max);
    int mappedY = (int)Remap(y, 0.0f, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, min, max);

    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, mappedX, mappedY, 0, 0);
}


public static float Remap(float value, float from1, float to1, float from2, float to2)
{
    return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
}
```

I think that's because cursor is still locked so the functions still tries to move the mouse. I have no more ideas how to do this.

[EDIT]: The problem is that the game uses Raw Input. How to send mouse input that will work as expected even if the raw input option is on?

Comment: If none of these functions work, it is very likely that the game uses Raw Input or some other mechanism to read data from the mouse. Why do you need to do this? Are you trying to write code to automate the game?

Comment: Yes, I am. The program should work in other programs too, but it's quite important for me to make it working in game(s). If it's using Raw Input - how to do the stuff then?

Comment: Okay, You were right. I had to switch off the ,,Raw Input" option in the game. The program works right now, but playing the game is now... a bit different. So I still want to make the program work while the Raw Input is on. Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: There is no good solution that I am aware of. The whole point of Raw Input is that you bypass the standard system input-processing functions and read the input yourself, directly. The game doing this obviously does not want to be automated. Lots of games will take even more drastic steps to prevent this type of cheating. Not sure if that applies here. Anyway, you could Google for "simulate raw input windows" and see what pops up. Like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591604/simulating-raw-input-on-windows).

Comment: I think that game doesn't use raw input to avoid cheaters, cause it allows to disable it in game menu (but then mouse can will move a bit different, because of input lag). I found this question before, but it's in C++ and I don't know how to implement it in C# (i'm weak at using WINAPI).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use kernel-mode library like `WinIO` to simulate raw inputs. (Hoperfully, your own program can work under user mode)